# Add reference to service within same project

Tags: asp.net, .net, wcf, web-services

I'm wondering if it is okay to add a reference to a web service within the same project (web application), i.e. I'm adding a reference in the same project where the service is defined.

The reason for doing so is because

- Hosting the service becomes easier (gets automatically hosted when hosting the web app).
- Invoking the service is done dynamically, i.e. the service url is fetched (from db) at run time and methods on that particular service are invoked. (this is a web app which is hosted on many domains. each app knows the service url of other apps (urls stored in db). since I have a reference to the service, I can change the url at runtime by updating the `Url` of the proxy and invoke it.)

Also, I'm not sure if this is the way to go about it. I have seen a lot of people suggest using WCF instead of a web service, but I don't see how I could accomplish the same thing with WCF.

There is already a question regarding this on SO - [Add Service Reference to WCF Service within Same Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2135954/add-service-reference-to-wcf-service-within-same-project), but i don't think it is valid for my situation.

Answer (score 1):

If the service is already in your project, you can use it directly without requiring a web service proxy.

After all, Web services are for exposing your application functionality to the outside world and not to other parts of your system.

Comment: Like I said, the service url is fetched at runtime (it could (and mostly will) be pointing to another web app) and invoked accordingly. So in effect, I'm accessing the functionality / data of that web app.

Comment: Better off moving your service(s) into a separate project in your solution. You can then discover and reference the service no problem

Comment: I could do that, but that would mean that every time I host a new copy of the web app, I would also have to host the web service. This effort is saved if I keep the web service in the same project as the web app. Anyway, why is this practice bad..?

Comment: Not sure if it's bad practice, but it doesn't make sense. If your service could potentially/probably be hosted in a different server then it makes sense to reflect that in your application solution by having it as a separate project. In terms of hosting, it doesn't make much difference because you can put it in a different virtual folder under the same IIS application.